# Creating Email Field Component in ExtJS6

Tags: javascript, extjs, code-duplication, extjs6, modular

I am a beginner and I am trying to create the login page using **ExtJS6**. The simplest way I can do this is to create a `panel` containing items such as 2 `text fields` (username and password) and the `button`,but since the email and password text field are going to be reused again in signup as well so I want to avoid code duplication. As in both places we are going to have same validation rules ,we are going to have to have same titles for email and password .

I am thinking of creating an email text field component class and password text field class which is going to be extended by `TextField` class and use properties such as `vtype`,`name` in these custom define classes and in my login form/Signup form I use these custom fields so I will be able to avoid code duplication.

I would like other members to comment on this and tell me if this is the right solution or not and if yes then how I am going to achieve this .

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extjs 6 already provides an [email](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-modern/#!/api/Ext.field.Email) and a [password](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.2-modern/#!/api/Ext.field.Password) texfield.
You can use their config properties to apply more validations.

You can create your own form panel like this:

```
Ext.define('App.view.LoginPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Register',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'emailfield',
                    label: 'Email',
                    name: 'email'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'passwordfield',
                    label: 'Password',
                    name: 'password'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

and use multiple instances of it where ever you want.

Comment: If we make login as a component then we are going to reduce the reusability circle and increase the code duplication Since this component as a whole is not going to be used again in the project but if we built it like units and make email textbox as component ,and set name ,validation properties in its component class and use it then we will enhance reusability and will we can avoid duplication as well.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to me to define a custom component like: Lets say you extend 'passwordfield' and set its name. 

Now when you have to reuse, you will write {xtype:'custom'}.
Instead of {xtype:'paswordfield', name:'password'}. Using Ext standard component is reuseability in itself. 
But its up to you and your requirements that what you should prefer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a need to create email and password field also, but for some reason ExtJS 6.2.0 GPL contains emailfield only in modern packages. My app showed `Ext.Loader` errors "404 not found / not defined" for `xtype: passwordfield` and `xtype: emailfield`. I checked in library on my disk and in repository (https://cdnjs.com/libraries/extjs/6.2.0) and really did not find them.

So I've done this alternatively - `xtype: 'textfield'` with options:

- `vtype: 'email'` for email (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.VTypes.html)
- `inputType: 'password'` for password (https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-inputType)